# Modelling a bitemporal data set in a data warehouse

Tags: database, database-design, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

I have a bitemporal EAV type model.

There are multiple attribute tables(one for each value data type(int_attributes, float_attributes, etc. )) looking like:

```
|id|field_id|value|as_of_date_start|as_of_date_end|system_date_start|system_date_end|
```

And a reference table for attributes:

```
|field_id|name|data_type|target_attribute_table|
```

It is possible to construct an entity and get all its attributes at any point in time by querying a union of all attribute value tables.

**Question**

I want to move this data to a data warehouse(Snowflake). I wasn't able to find a whole lot of info on moving bitemporal data to a warehouse and how to model it. I don't understand where would I need a facts and dimensions related modelling in this scenario. Also would it make any sense to pivot this table to get attributes as columns when loading the data in the system?

I'm thinking of moving this data as is to the warehouse.

The main use cases of this data is to get the current snapshot of data, get entire history of some entities and get histories of selected attributes on selected entities and do some analysis on them.

I'm very new to data modelling in a warehouse.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to model this as Slowly Changing Dimensions (probably Type 2). You'll probably need to reconstruct each entity for each time period where a specific set of attribute values were applicable and then insert these records into your Dimension tables

Comment: @NickW please confirm if my understanding is correct: I should create a table with all attributes as columns and add an entry for each entity for every day for past 20 years? That'd lead to a huge dataset as the data changes on a daily basis on some entities. And for 20 years of data with date as a dimension, 4k(days) rows each entity's snapshot every day would be astronomical. Also as I mentioned, attributes keep getting added, so this table would also reqiure ~weekly DDL changes which would also lead to some issues.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @philipxy updated it to mark my question

Comment: At one point you say, "Also [...]?". So I guess the 1st question is before that. What is it? And why do you go on after that? Please clearly ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question, not multiple ones. Also, it's not clear how this is different from asking for a textbook section & bespoke tutorial. So this "lacks focus". What is stopping you from putting this DB into a warehouse? Follow a published design method & ask about where you are first stuck. Also asking for off-site resources is off-topic. [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: *I'm thinking of moving this data as is to the warehouse.* If all you're doing is offloading the information to another database server to reduce the load on the production server, then sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would find it helpful to read a book on Dimensional Modelling - the "bible" is [The Data Warehouse Toolkit](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Definitive-Dimensional/dp/1118530802/ref=sr_1_1?crid=Y2ML0GJU51O0&dchild=1&keywords=ralph%20kimball&qid=1600851134&sprefix=ralph%20kimba%2Caps%2C144&sr=8-1)

To simplify things a lot, you need to do the following:

1. Define your entities (dimensions) e.g. Customer, Product, Country, Employee, etc.
2. Add the appropriate attributes to each entity
3. Add effective start and end dates attributes to each entity (to enable SCD2 logic)

For each record for each entity there will presumably be time periods when none of the attributes changed so you need to insert a record into the entity for each of these static periods. For example, if Customer A started off with a Value attribute of 1, then on 23rd Jan 2020 this was changed to 2 and then on 3rd August 2020 this was changed to 3 (and assuming no other attribute values changed during this time period for this Customer), you would end up with these records in your Customer Dimension:

[image]

Hope this helps?

Comment: Attributes keep on getting added, there is no fixed list. So every time an attribute gets added, I'll need to add it to this table as another column? Also if I go for this approach, won't it be harder for me to now query the history of a specific attribute on an entity, than before, because for _any_ attribute update, this entire entity will be updated.

Comment: OK - you seem to have a very specific set of data requirements and you already have them modelled in such a way that allows you to query them in the way you want - if I am understanding what you already have correctly? So my question would be why do you "... want to move this data to a data warehouse"? A data warehouse (at least in the traditional sense) is used for running analytical queries over large datasets; I would argue that querying the specific value of an attribute over time is not an analytical query

Comment: I want to run analytical queries in parallel on this dataset. Performance deteriorates on SQL server in case of such queries. Given that storage and all of compute on snowflake is separated and they claim any number of parallel models/queries can be run on any dataset without perf impact. Also this is a financial dataset about stocks. So IMO this is a valid analytical query to get 10 different indicators(attributes) like close price, volume, etc. For a set of shares in an industry if someone wants to fetch last 10 years of this data to do some computation on all these values.

Comment: I quite agree that "this is a valid analytical query to get 10 different indicators(attributes) like close price, volume, etc." but that was not what I was challenging, it was your statement "Attributes keep on getting added, there is no fixed list". Does stock information really generate new attributes constantly that you couldn't have identified when you were designing the dimensions? Adding new attributes is a relatively simple exercise and is not really a design issue, it is a build issue. If you really have a constant stream of new attributes then you need to develop slick CD/CI processes

Comment: this is really dependent on the data sources. We have multiple data sources and gather information about the financial instruments from different sources. The instruments themselves are of multiple types and have different attributes that get added/removed fairly regularly. This is more of a business problem that can not be avoided. To avoid DDL changes every now and then the EAV model was chosen. I'm not sure what you mean by CI CD process here.

Comment: Continuous Integration/Continuous Development - basically how you automate your build/test/deploy cycles so that you can release frequently with as little manual intervention as possible

Comment: I don't believe there is any "magic bullet" that would allow you to have an ever changing list of attributes loaded into anything that looks like a traditional star schema - without having to manage these changes just as you would any more "normal" inclusion of additional attributes. Even if you could come up with a structure that did enable this, you need to bear in mind that if the DB engine doesn't understand it then your query performance is likely to be horrible - for example (and I'm not saying this is a solution) if you dropped some sort of array structure into a VARIANT column

Comment: All of this is already automated, I thought you meant something specific in context of DB/warehouse. I see why it is difficult to come up with a data model and why this model could cause an issue. But I think we'll need to revisit our business requirements in this case. To have a more solid understanding of the expectations from this data. Thanks!